# Asp.net MVC core Bad Request - Request Too Long HTTP Error 400. The size of the request headers is too long

Tags: asp.net, cookies, asp.net-core, bad-request

Facing an issue with MVC core 2.0 web application on application startup in the browser it throwing a Bad Request - Request Too Long and HTTP Error 400, The size of the request headers is too long. Even though I cleared all the cookies. First time it will load again goes to bad request page.

Answer (score 2):

Are you doing authentication via AD by any chance? There is a probability where you are either part of too many groups or your identity has too many claims assigned. All that gets stuffed in your response header since they go into (multipart) cookies.